# Android studio gradle project refresh gives "Invalid argument"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have downloaded me friends android project. When I open it with android studio it starts to sync gradle. However it gives to me **invalid argument** error.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    maven { url 'http://audiobox.keytwo.net' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kz.itsolutions.businformator"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 20150105
        versionName "1.95"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode = true
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
 }

 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
     compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
     compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
     compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
     compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
     compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
     compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.2'
     compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
     compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
     compile files('libs/Parse-*.jar')
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4: 22.1.1'
 }
```

I think the main problen is the `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `midsdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. I have installed all avilable sdk versions and changed these numbers, stil does not work.

I think this project uses outdated gradle version which had different argument for something.

What needed to change to make project able to build?

Stack trace of my gradle is:

```
Gradle 'bus_informator' project refresh failed
    Error:Error:Invalid argument
```

I have tried to find similar questions, but I haven't found.

I have run `gradlew assemble --info` and it gave me that kind of error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: 
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:1.7.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
     http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.pom
     http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.jar
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.jar
     https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.pom
     https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.jar
     http://audiobox.keytwo.net/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.pom
     http://audiobox.keytwo.net/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.jar
     file:/D:/My path/Mobi/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.pom
     file:/D:/My path/Mobi/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.jar
     file:/D:/My path/Mobi/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.pom
     file:/D:/My path/Mobi/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/1.7.0/crashlytics-1.7.0.jar
 Required by:
     bus_informator:app:unspecified
```

Comment: Check fabric is install in your project.

Comment: What is fabric? Is it connected with crashlytics? How to check it?

Comment: install `Fabric plugin` for that. Search `Fabric.io` in _Google_

Comment: Change `classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'` with `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'` and `apply plugin: 'crashlytics'` with `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`. Also post the stacktrace of your gradle issue.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti it gives me an error: `could not find any version that matches io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+`

Comment: Sorry my bad.. You have also to change `maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }` with `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }`

Comment: I have changed all my `download.crashlytics.com` to `fabric.io` mavens. It took some time to sync but stil gives an error `invalid argument`.

Comment: run gradlew assemble --info

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti updated my question

Comment: Change this dependency with:
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by changing this

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/*.jar')
```

to this

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```